# This is servlet code to insert value into the database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
package car;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@WebServlet(name = "detail", urlPatterns = {"/detail"})

public class detail extends HttpServlet {
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

       throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {

        String name=request.getParameter("name");

        String emailid=request.getParameter("emailid");

        int mobile=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobile"));  

        String carname=request.getParameter("carname");

        int regno=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("regno"));

        int manufacturingyear=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("manufacturingyear"));

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","");

        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("insert into userdetail (name,emailid,mobile,carname,regno,manufacturingyear) values('"+name+"','"+emailid+"','"+mobile+"','"+carname+"','"+regno+"','"+manufacturingyear+"',)");

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        out.println("<html>");

        out.println("<head>");

        out.println("<title>Servlet detail</title>");            

        out.println("</head>");

        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<h1>FILL DETAILS</h1>");

        out.println("</body>");

        out.println("</html>");

    } catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {            
       out.close();
    }

}
```

The values are not inserting the given values into the database(userdetail).In database fields are showing null.

Field                 Datatype

name                  Text

emailid               Text

mobile                Int

carname               Text

regno                 Int

manufacturingyear     Int

Comment: Learn from your mistakes and improve your question.

Comment: value is not inserting into the table

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Think i done mistake in try part plz verify that

Comment: That's really too bad. We are not your debuggers. Figure it out yourself. If you don't understand why, give us an explanation of exactly what happens and we might help you. In the mean time, format your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis only the first field(name) is alone inserted into the table other fields are not inserted

Comment: I'm surprised that the call `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","")` isn't failing (it probably is, with the exception being written out in your far too general `catch` block) because that connection string looks like nonsense to me.  You need to indicate what database you're trying to write to, so that we can advise about that.  You should also read about SQL Inject Attacks and correct your code accordingly.

Comment: @NickHolt database is ms access

Comment: How to connect to MS Access with JDBC - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090994/insert-data-to-ms-access-from-java

Comment: st.executeUpdate("insert into userdetail (name,emailid,mobile,carname,regno,manufacturingyear) values('"+name+"','"+emailid+"','"+mobile+"','"+carname+"','"+regno+"','"+manufacturingyear+"')");

Answer (score 0):

You must extract a method for saving in the db, and put that method in a different class. Then add a main method to your db dedicated class and try inserting a row from the main method (not from your servlet).

Mixing form reading with db persistance and application logic is a too bad practice: you have the proof in your example: it's impossible to test your app without a server, and impossible to understand where is the problem

Comment: st.executeUpdate("insert into userdetail (name,emailid,mobile,carname,regno,manufacturingyear) values('"+name+"','"+emailid+"','"+mobile+"','"+carname+"','"+regno+"','"+manufacturingyear+"')");